# How to wait for an API to return JSON response and then console.log that response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fetch, es6-promise

In my code -

```
function longForLoop(limit) {
    var i = 0;
    var ref = setInterval(() => {
        console.log("\n-----------------------------\n");
      
      normUrl = "https://sih-utils.herokuapp.com/normal?a="+qActualNormal +"&b="+qIdeal;



      var obj;
      fetch(normUrl)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => obj = data)
        .then(() => console.log(obj))
      console.log(obj);


   
        
      i++;
      if (i == limit) {
          clearInterval(ref);
      }
    }, 2000);
  }
  
  longForLoop(2);
```

Following result is obtained -

[image]
When I run this code, **it says obj not defined**, I have 2 more similar calls to make to the same API below this and it returns some result that is stored in a variable, and in the end, I want to console.log the results obtained according to the order in which they were called.

Answer (score 0):

you probbly want to do something like this,

```
fetch(normUrl)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))

console.log(obj);
```

The above err may be caused by many reason, one of which it you might not have `obj` defined previously

Comment: @AdityaKulkarni please mark as answer  & upvote if it helped

Comment: No, obj has been defined in my code, console.log is showing undefined

Comment: is it in scope, include that in above example !!

Comment: I have updated the code , please take a look at it, and just assume that I have the values of qActualNormal and qIdeal in this case

Comment: This is what you are looking for: https://jsbin.com/miyofoheca/edit?js,console

Use the code in Node.js not sure about await in your browser